# How to add https support over nodejs app with apache on centos7

Tags: node.js, apache, ssl, centos

I have configure httpd (apache) on my virtual centos7 machine and added a ssl certificate from letsencrypt. I also configure it to pass all requests through https protocol.

### Problem

In my server I create many projects. Some of them are in php, some other on nodejs. The problem is that when I run a nodejs app, even if the console message says that it runs as expected on my port (8080) it will not load on my browser.

### What do I expect

Assume that the domain is example.com and the project folder is named blog, I want to use the following url to access it https://example.com/blog

### Apache configurations

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    # SET STRICT TRANSPORT SECURITY
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf


SSLCompression off
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH$
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload"
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
SSLUseStapling on
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/stapling-cache(150000)"
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
```

## My Virtual host configurations

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache/example.com/error.log
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;"

    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"

    Options -Indexes
</VirtualHost>
```

## The index.js file of the node project

```
/********************** APP DEPENDENCES AND CONFIGURES ************************/
// Include required modules
var compression = require('compression');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var MYSQL_db = require('./models/database/MYSQL');
var helper = require('./models/utils/functions');
var util = require('util');
require('./models/utils/extend_prototype');

// Include global configure file
var GLOBAL_VAR = require('./config/global');

// Include environmental specific configure file
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    case 'development':
        var ENV_VAR = require('./config/dev');
        app.locals.url_prefix = ENV_VAR.URL_PREFIX_PATH;
        break;
    case 'production':
        var ENV_VAR = require('./config/production');
        app.locals.url_prefix = ENV_VAR.URL_PREFIX_PATH;
        break;
    default:
        console.error("Unrecognized NODE_ENV: " + process.env.NODE_ENV);
        process.exit(1);
}

// Configure express static files and template language to use
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Configure the middlewares
app.use(compression());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// 'Can't set headers after they are sent', fix
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var _send = res.send;
    var sent = false;
    res.send = function(data) {
        if (sent) return;
        _send.bind(res)(data);
        sent = true;
    };
    next();
});

app.get(ENV_VAR.URL_PREFIX_PATH + '/', function(req, res) {
    // render the view
});


app.listen(GLOBAL_VAR.PORT, function() {

    console.log('Listening on port ' + GLOBAL_VAR.PORT + '!');
});
```

### My global.js and productions.js configuration files

```
// Global.js
module.exports = {
    PORT: 8080
}

// Production.js
module.exports = {
    URL_PREFIX_PATH: '/blog'
}
```

I run the project with the following command:

```
NODE_ENV=production node /var/www/html/blog/app/app.js
```

How is it possible to access the page on top of the default 443 port? I tried to add https module on nodejs, add proxy to apache, but it didn't worked.

Comment: If you place simple `index.html` at `/var/www/html`, does `http://example.com/index.html` open? What about  `http://example.com:8080/`

Comment: @DusanBajic all `http` requests are transfered to `https`. So `http://example.com/index.html` will open but as `https`. `http://example.com:8080/` will transfered  again as `https://example.com:8080/` and it won't open.

Comment: What is the exact error in browser?

Comment: @DusanBajic nothing, just keeps loading forever! -.- (This grey loading bar that indicates browser is trying to connect to the page)

Comment: Your apache is probably not listening on port 443. Unless there is separate `ssl.conf`, you need to add `Listen 443 https` line to your `httpd.conf`. Also you need separate <VirtualHost *:443> block for https site. (and of course make sure mod_ssl is installed0

Comment: @DusanBajic can you add an answer please?I'll check it right now.

Comment: @DusanBajic nope I get error. `Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` I revert the changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126959/discussion-between-dusan-bajic-and-georgegkas).